# How do I overload `+` on a NamedTuple

Tags: python, mypy

How do I create a custom overloading of plus for a named tuple in 3.5? I know there's some new syntax in 3.6 for this, can you do it in 3.5? I want it also to pass mypy checks.

```
from typing import NamedTuple


Point = NamedTuple('Point',[('x',int),
                            ('y',int)])

def joinPoints(a: Point, b:Point) -> Point:
    return Point(x = a.x+b.x,y=a.y+b.y)

q = Point(1,2)
r = Point(3,4)
s= joinPoints(q,r)
t = q+r #HOW DO I MAKE THIS GO?
#s should equal t
```

Comment: What new syntax are you referring to? You need to subclass the namedtuple and override `__add__`

Comment: You would have to create a sub class to define `__add__`

Comment: I don't want a subclass, I want trait/type-based dispatch like the functional languages :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a note, what the new, class-based syntax for defining typed namedtuples in Python 3.6 is ultimately doing at runtime is basically a bunch of metaprogramming hijinkery to make a custom class, which happens to also contain your custom `__add__` method, if you included one.

Since we can't have that syntax in Python 3.5, the best you can really do is to just implement all that boilerplate yourself, I'm afraid.

Remember, namedtuples are basically meant to be a convenient way of defining simple classes (that subclass tuple), nothing more. If you want anything more complex, you're actually going to need to implement it yourself.

---

In any case, setting aside types completely, there isn't a super clean way of doing what you're trying to do at *runtime*, much less with types (at least, to the best of my knowledge). I guess one sort of clean way would be to manually patch the Point class after you define it, like so:

```
from typing import NamedTuple

Point = NamedTuple('Point', [('x', int), ('y', int)])

def add(self: Point, other: Point) -> Point:
    return Point(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)

Point.__add__ = add

a = Point(1, 2)
b = Point(3, 4)

print(a + b)  # prints 'Point(4, 6)'
```

However, you'd have to give up on using mypy then -- mypy makes the simplifying (and usually reasonable) assumption that a class's attributes and type signatures will not change after that class has been defined, and so will disallow assigning a new method to Point and will consequently will throw an error on the last line.

Perhaps there's some cleverer approach (maybe using the abc module somehow?) that ends up satisfying you, the Python runtime, and mypy, but I'm currently not aware of such an approach.